# Fluent Nhibernate where clause one to many

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I want to create a joined query between one to many entities. As i give the example above;

UserEntity

```
    public class UserEntity
    {
      public virtual int Id {get;set;}
      public virtual IList<Card> Cards{get;set;}

    }
```

And CardEntity

```
    public class CardEntity
    {
      public virtual int Id {get;set;}
      public virtual int CardNumber {get;set;}
      public virtual UserEntity User{get;set;}
    }
```

UserMapping

```
    public UserEntityMap()
    {
        Table("user");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        HasMany(x => x.Cards).KeyColumn("User_Id").Fetch().Join();

    }
```

CardMapping

```
    public CardEntityMap()
    {
        Table("card");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.CardNumber);
        References(x => x.User).Column("User_id");
    }
```

Query

```
 var query = _session.QueryOver<UserEntity>();
 if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cardNumber)
 {
   query.Where(x=>x.Cards.Any(c=>c.CardNumber == cardNumber)) /// Tried this get an error  
 }
```

I was hoping to see an output like

```
Select * from user u join card c on c.user_id=u.id where c.number=cardNumber
```

I know there must be a logical way to do this but i couldnt find out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using NHibernate.Linq instead of QueryOver?

If you put a 'using NHibernate.Linq' at the top of the file, you would be able to use

```
_session.Query<UserEntity>();
```

instead which might give you the result you are looking for.

Alternatively (using QueryOver), you might look to use a JoinAlias:

```
Card card; // Used for alias below

query.JoinAlias(u => u.Cards, () => card)
     .Where(() => card.CardNumber == cardNumber)
```

Comment: Good spot! ;) Yeah, `.Any` goes with LINQ === Query, not QueryOver

Comment: thanks for the answer :) i will give the JoinAilas a try. I tried Query instead of QueryOver but there was some properties that i needed on QueryOver so i used it. I was confused about using JoinAlias or JoinQueyOver beacuse i tought that there must be an easier way or a better way to create the query. But i think i was wrong